# Ember.js - how to render default outlet in a component view

Tags: ember.js, routes, components, render, ember-cli

I have a reused component view called 'box-modal.js' in **/app/templates/components/box-modal.js**.
It contains an outlet in which I want to render a default template.

```
<div>
  {{outlet main}}
</div>
```

The template I want to render as default in the outlet is in **/app/templates/default_box.hbs**

I know that you can use renderTemplate function in a router file for regular templates but it's not working for component templates:

**/app/routes/components/box-modal.js**

```
import Ember from "ember";

var BoxModalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('default_box', {
      into: 'components.box-modal',
      outlet: 'main'
    });
}
export default BoxModalRoute;
```

Is there a standardized way for template rendering in component views in Ember-cli?

Comment: Just to check, but you are exporting the route you have created, `export default BoxModelRoute;`, correct? Have you checked that renderTemplate is hit?

Comment: oh, yea i did the export. i'll edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A component should be an isolated thing in your application, so idealy it should not have access, or depend on external things.

What you can do is use your component to wrap the template.

```
<div class="modal-component">
  {{yield}}
</div>
```

And then wrap your template in the component.

```
{{#box-modal}}
  {{partial "default_box"}}
{{/box-modal}}
```

To be used as partial your template name should start with underscore **/app/templates/_default_box.hbs**

Would generate

```
<div class="modal-component">
  <whatever is in /app/templates/_default_box.hbs />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by using my component to wrap a template?

Comment: Use your component as a block, and put your template inside.

Comment: Leading underscore for partials is no longer necessary. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2242 and https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3017

Comment: Awesome, docs still need to be updated then. http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper

Comment: would this work with actions? I have a list of clickable items that need to render a partial based on which item was clicked. How can I render a different partial in this situation?

Comment: This would work with actions, not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, yeah it's kinda hard to explain my situation without images but i'll try. I have a modal with a few links in it, each display a different view inside that modal. When the modal first opens, it should display a default view and from there will change depending on which item was clicked. Is that clear at all?

Answer (score 0):

Component extends a View, so similarly to the View components have a `layoutName` and `templateName` properties. You can use these properties to specify how to display your template. See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/adding-layouts-to-views/) for an official description.

So, for example, your component can look as follows:

```
App.BoxModalComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  layoutName: "box_modal",
  templateName: "box_modal_template"
});
```

And your layout and template can look as follows:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="box_modal">
    <h2>Box Modal</h2>

    {{ yield }}
  </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="box_modal_template">
  <h4>Inside Box Modal</h4>
 </script>
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cutito/1/edit)

**UPDATE**

Also, if you are using a template that is expecting to render out some context that context will need to be passed into the component since component is isolated from your routes/controllers (as @Asgaroth points out in his answer).

See the following example for how to pass context => component => template http://emberjs.jsbin.com/baminu/2/edit